# How to show time in FullCalendar horizontaly in day view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Here is example what i need.

[image: example]

Will this grid be supported by plugin or how can i do this?

Comment: Full calender doesn't seem to support this view.

Comment: for now yes, but may be it would be implemented